# generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm using the Google App Engine plugin for Eclipse (4.2) and Google App Engine SDK 1.9.2

So the project consists of a server side application (backend) and an Android app (frontend). I incidentally checked the "uses Google App Engine" within the project properties page of the frontend. Since I unchecked that again, I can't compile the Android app - getting the error below.

Any idea how to solve that without deleting my project?

> There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud
>   Endpoints classes: Project Notes is not a web-app project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had the same problem, but we had to delete and re-import the project in order to fix it:

App Engine was enabled in preferences, which made it add a whole bunch of libraries when we checked out Android project from repository. The error wouldn't go away after fixing build path.

Our solution (we had a working Android project in repository):

1. Remove App Engine from Eclipse Preferences
2. Delete project
3. Check out the project from repository
4. Re-add App Engine

You could also try the following after removing App Engine:

- Remove project from workspace, then import it again
- Close and Open project in Eclipse (right-click, close project)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the solution is even easier. If you have removed Google AppEngine from the project:

1. delete the marker for this error
2. Clean project
3. Rebuild, the error marker should not come back